# HTML table height & width size scaling proportionately

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table with a single cell in it. 
The table expands according to the content inside the cell.

My problem is that I want the table to preserve a square size, so that if the width scales, the height will scale proportionally. I need the same functionality like image scaling even though the content is text.

Comment: I think you'll need javascript for that...

Comment: Since certain CSS properties only apply to certain objects... what type of contents will be in the cell/table?

Comment: @ChristopherJSmith regular text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is an example

```
<body onLoad="tableSquare('table1');">
  <table class="square" id="table1" >
    <tr>
      <td>lalalalalallc sald;asd;l</td>
      <td>gf sdfgds gdsf gdsfg dfg dfg</td>
      <td>dfg dfgdf gxcvxcvxcvxcvxcvxcvxc jhkvxcvxcvdfgdfgdf gdfg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>dfg dfgdfg dfgdfg</td>
      <td>dfg dfgdf </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Style

```
.square{
  background-color:#cfcfcf;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

Javascript Function

```
function tableSquare(tableName){
  var t = document.getElementById(tableName);
  var max_size = Math.max(t.offsetWidth,t.offsetHeight);
  t.style.width = max_size+"px";
  t.style.height = max_size+"px";
}
```

Demo page on JSBIN  http://jsbin.com/ivepak/1/edit

Comment: Well answered, Natalia.
I played around a little with this code and was able to restore auto-sizing by adding the commands `t.style.width="100%"; t.style.height="100%";` just before the line with the Math.max() call.